# Extract a pattern with some special characters as well

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract a pattern that lies inside a couple of square braces. They usually look like this:
  `this is what I want[Pat1 France�s Wal-mart  ] and this is [Pat2 boy-o-boy  ]`
My regex looks like this:

```
Pattern search = Pattern.compile("\\[[\\w.\\.\\-\\s]+]");
```

How can I incorporate the special character or what should I change in my pattern to extract any character that can appear in those braces?

I want to extract [Pat1 France�s Wal-mart] and [Pat2 boy-o-boy  ] somehow. I can extract the pat2 portion. Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
\\[.*?\\]
```

Answer (score 1):

just use `.` which matches any character.

```
 String s= "[Pat1 France�s Wal-mart ]";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[.*?\\]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        System.out.println(m.find() + " " + m.group());
```

Comment: you are missing `?` else it would match greedily

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ true .. thanks , i was more concerened about the output :P